# Installing Numpy on PyCharm (Linux)

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, ide, jetbrains-ide

I have been trying since morning to make this right and just learn maths! but no! Can someone please help me with this?

**EDIT:** What I have been trying to do (video GIF): https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkVkY.jpg

```
Details: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/bob/Music/pycharm-community-2022.1.2/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py", line 73, in run_pip
runpy.run_module(module_name, run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 210, in run_module
return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 97, in _run_module_code
_run_code(code, mod_globals, init_globals,
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/__main__.py", line 29, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete
File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/autocompletion.py", line 10, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser
File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main_parser.py", line 8, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions
File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/cmdoptions.py", line 23, in <module>
from pip._internal.cli.parser import ConfigOptionParser
File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
from pip._internal.configuration import Configuration, ConfigurationError
File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/configuration.py", line 26, in <module>
from pip._internal.utils.logging import getLogger
File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/logging.py", line 13, in <module>
from pip._internal.utils.misc import ensure_dir
File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 40, in <module>
from pip._internal.locations import get_major_minor_version, site_packages, user_site
File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
from . import _distutils, _sysconfig
File "/home/bob/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip/_internal/locations/_distutils.py", line 9, in <module>
from distutils.cmd import Command as DistutilsCommand
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'distutils.cmd'
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it on my own.
I had multiple versions of Python downloaded and that might have caused the problem. So, I restored PyCharm to it's default settings by going to

```
File--->Manage IDE Settings--->Restore Default Settings
```

I am pretty sure I had not chosen the right base interpreter previous time, but this time I choose base interpreter

```
/usr/bin/python3.10
```

(the highest installed in my system)

and clicked on

*Inherit global site-packages

*Make available to all packages

[image: New Project config that worked]

and I let all the packages which needed to be downloaded to be downloaded. And, that's about it. It worked. Now I can import numpy or any other packages or add packages to my project.

This was trial and error. I don't know what caused what, if someone does know, edits will be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this in your terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils

sudo apt-get install python3-apt
```

and then:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall numpy
```

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/8A5YjMQ
Hey, I got UNABLE TO LOCATE PACKAGE NUMPY ERROR

Comment: What about 'pip install numpy' or 'pip3 intall numpy'?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/UpSTCLj They all are installed.